# How to use IPriorityQueue in the C5 Library

Tags: c#, heap, priority-queue, binary-heap, c5

I am using the popular C5 library for C# ([C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5)) and I'm trying to figure out how to implement the `IPriorityQueue` properly. Lets say I have the set `A={5,4,1,2,3}`. I want the priority to be the highest integer value. How do I implement this?

Could someone please give an example of where I add the elements in set `A` one by one to the queue? Where can you specify the priority property? Kinda lost on the implementation.

The ultimate goal by the way is to use this to make a binary heap.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at their [IntervalHeap](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/heaps/IntervalHeap.cs) implementation for an example of implementing `IProirityQueue`. You can use my [simple heap of integers](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/30/a-simple-heap-of-integers/) as an example of a heap implementation that you should be able to modify to implement their `IPriorityQueue`. I wrote quite a bit about binary (and d-ary) heaps a few years ago. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/12/18/posting-the-heap-code/ for the whole series.

Comment: So do you use IPriorityQueue instead of a list? What does that syntax look like?

     public  Mylist<T> : IPriorityQueue<T>  ?

Comment: Are you familiar with implementing interfaces in C#?

Comment: still new to the language a bit, so not really haha. I would really appreciate a quick example of how to use this thing properly. I guess it's just an interface, so I should look that up more. Nice blog btw!

Comment: Here's my node code so far: https://pastebin.com/mbK8An5m . I guess to maintain the shape property of a heap I should add a left and right option :/

Comment: Or you know... make a fib heap or pairing heap and to hell with structure :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that C5 library, but there's an easy-to-use, high-performance priority queue implementation here:

[PriorityQueue source](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/e740e7c10f405a41cdedc9b778f30059d6d22936/SharpByte.Core/Collections/PriorityQueue.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[ConcurrentPriorityQueue source](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/e740e7c10f405a41cdedc9b778f30059d6d22936/SharpByte.Core/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentPriorityQueue.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (if you need thread safety)

Using one of those, you would construct it this way:

```
IPriorityQueue<object> queue = new PriorityQueue<object>(5, true);
```

where 5 is the number of priorities you want to manage, true/false specifies whether you want the priorities to be considered to be descending or ascending in priority, and <object> would be your generic type. Both of these support full list operations as well. There's also a [project website](http://sharpbyte.net/).